# swig/sphinxbase/ad.i:56: Error: Unable to find 'pybuffer.i'

Tags: python, speech-recognition, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I have been trying to install the pocketsphinx package
with pip for python3.6.3 on Mac os x 10.6.8 but the package failed to install an I get these errors:

swig/sphinxbase/ad.i:56: Error: Unable to find 'pybuffer.i'

swig/sphinxbase/ad.i:99: Error: Unable to find 'pybuffer.i'

error: command 'swig' failed with exit status 1.

I already have swig installed. I don't know what the problem is  or even worst how to solve it. Thank you!.

Comment: Check your swig version and update if not recent.

Comment: Thank you the version I installed is version 3.0

Comment: It might be you also have an old version somewhere. You can try to run `which swig` to check what is actually used. You can also check if the file `$swig_prefix/share/swig/$version/python/pybuffer.i` is actually there.

Comment: Thank you once more. When i run which swig it gives me /usr/bin/swig

Comment: I asked you is there a file pybuffer.i in `/usr/share/swig/3.0/python` folder